# Cordova media plugin : CDVFile.h not found

Tags: cordova, plugins, media

I have installed the cordova media plugin using below command

```
    $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

But when i run my project it gives error in "CDVSound.m" file that "CDVFile.h not found"

Am I missing any step?

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem and wasted a few hours looking for the solution. 
This plugin requires the file plugin, which you can install via the following command:

```
cordova plugin add git://git.apache.org/cordova-plugin-file.git
```